# Problem with variable lecture in R, with decimal

Tags: r, data-cleaning

In a data frame with big values in euros (€), I found three difficulties:

1º Euro symbol is not read, interprets by the program as â‚¬. I have ommitted it with

```
gsub("â‚¬", "", nombrevariable)
```

2º I will like to replace commas by docs in order to permit R recognize them. Being large figures and omitting the first point, ie:

```
datossubvencion <− sub(".", "", datos$subvencion, fixed = TRUE)
```

Up here, all right.

3º I cannot do mathematical operations taping

```
as.numeric()
```

in the values. Ordering

```
summary()
```

R executes average, median and quartiles, but I cannot do it by myself, R returns me NA value.

I would like to know what I could do about it.

Other things that I have tried when loading the file is to add the `dec = ","`, or do it by the `read.csv2`, I have even added the `stringsAsFactors = F`, but still impossible.

And the last one, I tried to downdload data by Excel. R change itself "," to ".", and give me `summary()`. But also I can not use `rowSums` or something like that.

First lines of my .csv:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVRcr.jpg)

And my codes:

> datos<-read.csv("datos.csv",header = T,stringsAsFactors=F, sep=",")
>
> datos$subvencion<-gsub("â‚¬", "", datos$subvencion)
>   datos$costes.salariales<-gsub("â‚¬", "", datos$costes.salariales)
>   datos$costes.laborales<-gsub("â‚¬", "", datos$costes.laborales)
>
> datos$subvencion <- sub(".", "", datos$subvencion, fixed = TRUE)
>   datos$subvencion <- sub(".", "", datos$subvencion, fixed = TRUE)
>   datos$subvencion <- sub(",", ".", datos$subvencion, fixed = TRUE)
>   datos$subvencion<-as.numeric(datos$subvencion)
>
> colSums(datos[,"subvencion"])
>
> Error in colSums(datos[, "subvencion"]):    'x' must be an array of at
>   least two dimensions

And when I ask for the summary, it answer:

> summary(datos$subvencion)    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.
>   Max.    NA's   127094  197829  235085  351821  376482 3164334       1

And another:

> colSums(datos[ , "subvencion", drop = FALSE])

The answer is:

> subvencion NA

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a reproducible example of your data. Maybe copy and paste the first few lines (from the .csv - file opened in a text-editor) and specify the code you are using to read in the data. Think about what we need to reproduce your problem when posting a question.

Comment: Have you tried different encodings (using `encoding = ` argument of `read.csv`) to solve the problem with the Euro symbol?

Comment: I think Euro symbol it's not the problem, because when I eliminated it, the problem go on.

Comment: Please edit your question and do not post additional information as answers. Also don't post your data as images.

Comment: @csf It's cleaner to use good encoding than use this strange `gsub()`. And this problem of encoding is maybe still there after. `sep=","` cannot work with `dec=","` except if item are enclosed by `"`.

Comment: are commas "big-number marks" (e.g. 5,000,231) or decimal separators (e.g. 3,14159) ? Or both (dots as big-number marks, commas as decimal sep: 5.000.231,45) ?

Comment: Are both Ben Bolker

Comment: philip_b and what you suggest? that I edit first my .csv archive before to add into R ?

Comment: example of numeric european conversion to US default R decimal `as.numeric(sub(",",".",sub(".", "", list ("-1,2","1.400,5"), fixed = TRUE)))`

Comment: "philip_b and what you suggest?" The datas of the screenshot work, (except euro), so it seems that your datas are enclosed by double quote, therefore in this case comma in sep and dec could work.

Comment: Thank philip_b for your answer. But it is not enough. One line of my csv is: "1.377.063,53â‚¬","3.304.682,82â‚¬","3.361.248,71â‚¬",75,0FICIAL 1Âª (OF. VARIOS),8,09 M,"1.112,36",86

Comment: In your example: as.numeric(sub(",",".",sub(".", "", list ("-1,2","1.400,5"), fixed = TRUE))) can be: as.numeric(sub(",",".",sub(".", "", list (datos$subvencion), fixed = TRUE)))

Comment: It doen't work because numbers are so long, so I need to change "." to "" two times

Comment: The problem was very very simple: There is one NA...so I can't calculate anything

Comment: have a look for UTF-8 encoding